# How to make a search filter in all array elements

Tags: javascript

I have this

```
rows=[
  {label1 : "abc", label2 : "bcd"}, 
  {label3 : "cde", label4 : "dce"}
 ]
```

I tried

```
if(this.query.length > 1){  
 rows = rows.filter(row=>row.label1.toLowerCase().includes(this.query))
}
```

but I need to search in all "rows[]" labels not only 1 when I start a query
something like

```
rows = rows.filter(row=>row.label1.toLowerCase().includes(this.query))&& 
   rows.filter(row=>row.label2.toLowerCase().includes(this.query))... etc
```

I expect to get as example label1 and label2 results when I search letter "b" a common letter between them

Comment: please post ur expected output.

Comment: At present it looks like it will be an exception,, some elements of your array don't have a label1, then row.label1.toLowerCase() is no good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can mix `some` with `Object.values` to search all the values in the objects:

```js
let rows=[
  {label1 : "a", label2 : "b"}, 
  {label3 : "c", label4 : "d"}
 ]

function findInValues(arr, filter){
  return arr.filter(obj => Object.values(obj).some(v => v.includes(filter)))

}

 console.log(findInValues(rows, 'd'))
 console.log(findInValues(rows, 'a'))
 console.log(findInValues(rows, 'notHere'))
```

Comment: I get TypeError: v.includes is not a function
 :(

Comment: @BryanLesai are you getting that error here in the snippet or in your own code (or both)? It sounds like maybe you are working in an environment without all the benefits of modern JS. If you are working in an unusual environment (maybe google apps script), you should mention it in the question and maybe someone will have a good workaround.

Comment: I think the problem is I gave a basic example of it... but in my real code I have an array of objects and some of that objects contains another objects inside too ... thats why I get that error :/

Comment: Yeah @BryanLesai, that makes things a little more complex. Still you can probably do something with a relatively simple recursive function (you'll probably find some good examples if you search the archives here).

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a binary search. This is elementary, but you can modify the `filterRecord` to work recursively.

**Update:** I created [a recursive version](https://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/wjk45bfx/) for nested trees.

```js
const OPERANDS = [ 'and', 'or' ]; // Not used

// You need to convert the string to a binary tree or use the one below.
var rawQuery = 'label3="c" and label4="d"';
var query = {
  'and' : {
    'label3' : 'c',
    'label4' : 'd'
  }
}

var data = [
  { label1: "a", label2: "b" },
  { label3: "c", label4: "d" }
];

console.log(filter(data, query));

function filter(data, query) {
  return query != null ? data.filter(record => filterRecord(record, query)) : data;
}

function filterRecord(record, query) {
  return Object.keys(query).some((operand) => {
    var args = Object.keys(query[operand]);
    var leftKey = args[0];
    var leftVal = query[operand][args[0]]; // add check if object and recurse
    var rightKey = args[1];
    var rightVal = query[operand][args[1]]; // add check if object and recurse
    var fields = Object.keys(record);
    switch (operand) {
      case 'or':
        if (fields.includes(leftKey) || fields.includes(rightKey)) {
          return record[leftKey] === leftVal || record[rightKey] === rightVal;
        }
      case 'and':
        if (fields.includes(leftKey) && fields.includes(rightKey)) {
          return record[leftKey] === leftVal && record[rightKey] === rightVal;
        }
    }
    return false;
  });
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: nice answer. you should adjust the inputs so that the program looks like it's doing something. in the current example, the output is the same as the input.

Comment: @user633183 Updated, thanks. I am actually attempting to create a recursive solution. The main problem is I would face with this is creating the binary search tree from a query string... that is why I left that out.

Comment: @user633183 I created a recursive version here that used a nested-tree. https://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/wjk45bfx/

Answer (score 1):

You want it to filter all keys then. I'm assuming you don't know the keys before hand because then you'd just hard code it in the filter condition. I.e.

```
rows=[
  {label1 : "a", label2 : "b"}, 
  {label3 : "c", label4 : "d"}
 ]

if (this.query) {
  rows = rows.filter(row => row.label1.toLowerCase().includes(this.query) || row.label2.toLowerCase().includes(this.query))
}
```

if you need it to be dynamic, you can use the `some` method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on an array of the *keys* of the object. Try something like this:

```
rows=[
  {label1 : "a", label2 : "b"}, 
  {label3 : "c", label4 : "d"}
 ]

if (this.query) {
  rows = rows.filter(row => Object.keys(row).some(k => row[k].toLowerCase().includes(this.query))
}
```

Note: I saw someone beat me to the punch,. Since theirs abstracts the logic into a function and this one doesn't, I'll keep this up. perhaps it'll help understand the logic.